# populate Jagged Array with files C#

Tags: c#, file, jagged-arrays

I can't seem to figure out how to work with Jagged Arrays and Files. I have three files with numbers in them and wan to read each file into its own array. This is what I have so far. Was trying to populate the [0] array but to no avail. Any help appreciated. Can't find any tutorials on doing this, either.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamWriter section1;
    StreamWriter section2;
    StreamWriter section3;
    StreamReader section1read;
    StreamReader section2read;
    StreamReader section3read;

    section1 = File.CreateText("Section1.txt");
    section2 = File.CreateText("Section2.txt");
    section3 = File.CreateText("Section3.txt");

    int[][] Scores = new int[3][];

    Random randnum = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
    {
        int num = randnum.Next(55, 99);
        section1.WriteLine(num);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
    {
        int num1 = randnum.Next(55, 99);
        section2.WriteLine(num1);
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
    {
        int num3 = randnum.Next(55, 99);
        section3.WriteLine(num3);
    }

    section1.Close();
    section2.Close();
    section3.Close();

    section1read = File.OpenText("Section1.txt");

    int nums = 0;
    while (!section1read.EndOfStream)
    {
        Scores[0][nums] = int.Parse(section1read.ReadLine());
        ++nums;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Scores.Length; ++i)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(Scores[0][i]);
    }
    section1read.Close();
}
```

Comment: `Scores.Length`--> `Scores[0].Length` ?  What is going wrong?  Compile error, exception?

Comment: Is anything showing up in listbox? Looks like that bug with Scores[0].Length would cause only the first item to show up.

Comment: I'm getting a NullReferenceException Unhandled error on the section1read.ReadLine()

Comment: @AaronLS nothing shows up in the listbo

Comment: @MD.Unicorn just updated my comment. NullReferenceException Unhandled error on the section1read.ReadLine()

Comment: How is `Scores` declared and initialized? You need to show all your code.

Comment: @healix Tip:when you get nullreferenceexception, put breakpoint on the line and add to watch the various things on the line being dereferenced, `Scores`, `Scores[0]`, `section1read` to see who is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jagged arrays should be initialized in two steps:

1. The array itself:

   ```
   int[][] Scores = new int[3][];
   ```
2. The sub-arrays:

   ```
   Scores[0] = new int[12];
   Scores[1] = new int[8];
   Scores[2] = new int[10];
   ```

Array is a fixed length data structure. If you don't know the size in advance, you have to use a dynamic length structure. The best option is [`List<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class:

```
List<List<int>> scores = new List<List<int>>();

scores.Add( new List<int>() );

using( StreamReader section1read = File.OpenText("Section1.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = section1read.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        scores[0].Add(int.Parse(line));
    }
}
```

Here are other things to consider:

- Use a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block make sure any unmanaged resources associated with file is disposes.
- You can check the return value of [`StreamReader.ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) to determine the end of file

Comment: Here's another one of my problems. Do jagged arrays have to always be initialized? What if I don't know the size?

Comment: @MD.Unicorn I'm not familiar with the using block in this context. How is it used for unmanaged resources?

Comment: @healix See the link to the `using` statement in the asnwer (I made the `using` word a link). *Unmanaged resource* means anything outside the control of CLR (.NET runtime). The StreamReader class has some unmanaged resources (the file handle). Calling `Close` actually frees those resources, but using a `using` block a safer. Just google "c# using statement".

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Quote:

"Before you can use jaggedArray, its elements must be initialized. You can initialize the elements like this:

jaggedArray[0] = new int[5];

jaggedArray[1] = new int[4];

jaggedArray[2] = new int[2];"

So, what you're doing in your code is initializing a jagged array of three int[]s that are all set to null. If you don't create the array at each index before attempting to assign to it, nothing is there.

It seems what you want, though, is dynamic allocation - you don't know how many integers you need to store when you wrote the program. In this case, you should learn about the class `List<>`. `List<>` is like an array except you can add to and remove from the number of elements it has at runtime, rather than declaring it has a fixed size, using `Add` and `Remove`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Comment: I know about List<> but I was trying to see if this was possible with a jagged array because I never user them

Comment: @healix It's possible with a jagged array if you can initialize its number of elements to the exact number you need in advance. If this does not describe your use case, use a List.

Comment: So a jagged array always needs to know the size? It can't be dynamically allocated?

Comment: @healix You can initialize it with the contents of a variable, like `jaggedArray[0] = new int[numberOfElements];` but unless you read through a file, decide how many entries you'll make from it, THEN read through the file AGAIN after initializing the jagged array, it's not helpful.

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate it. The jagged array was driving me insane.